# Having trouble installing cpp-ethereum from homebrew

Tags: installation, build-from-source, homebrew

Been trying to install cpp-ethereum for development, but I keep running into issues with homebrew. Was hoping one of you had encountered something similar.

```
 ==> cmake -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/cpp-ethereum/1.3.0 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK=LAST -DCMAKE_VER
Last 15 lines from /Users/ryan/Library/Logs/Homebrew/cpp-ethereum/01.cmake:
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/super/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/super/clang++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at cmake/EthCompilerSettings.cmake:68 (message):
  This compiler AppleClang 8.1.0.8020042 is not able to compile required
  libff.  Install clang 4+ from Homebrew.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:94 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/cpp-ethereum-20170904-66078-15y3sg0/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

If reporting this issue please do so at (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core):
https://github.com/ethereum/homebrew-ethereum/issues

These open issues may also help:
brew install cpp-ethereum error https://github.com/ethereum/homebrew-ethereum/issues/121
brew install cpp-ethereum CMake Error https://github.com/ethereum/homebrew-ethereum/issues/124
Mac OS X 10.12.5 install error https://github.com/ethereum/homebrew-ethereum/issues/120
Error installing go-ethereum on Mac OS X https://github.com/ethereum/homebrew-ethereum/issues/117
Mining on MacBookPro issue https://github.com/ethereum/homebrew-ethereum/issues/111
Add a dependency on jsoncpp for solidity? https://github.com/ethereum/homebrew-ethereum/issues/123
Macbook Pro - Radeon Pro 560 4GB of GDDR5 issues https://github.com/ethereum/homebrew-ethereum/issues/122
Error when installing Solidity compiler https://github.com/ethereum/homebrew-ethereum/issues/96
```